# Skorch: Use AUC instead of ACC for validation

Tags: skorch

When I'm running `net.fit(X,y)` in `skorch` it prints out all the good stuff - is there a way to change the validation function to e.g AUC, F1 or some third function instead of the standard accuracy? Or, if not possible, is there a way to extact the validation set from the net, and compute it "manually"?

Answer (score 2):

You can use any sklearn metric you want in combination with the [EpochScoring](https://skorch.readthedocs.io/en/stable/callbacks.html#skorch.callbacks.EpochScoring) callback, thus AUC and F1 work just fine. Take a look at this [notebook](https://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/skorch-dev/skorch/blob/master/notebooks/Basic_Usage.ipynb#Callbacks) to see how it works in practice. You may even implement your own metric, as long as it conforms to the sklearn API.